# Updating active navbar link in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, nav

I'm using React to make a simple navbar that will color the currently active link.

```
import styles from "./styles.module.css"

export function Navbar() {
    return (
    <nav className="nav">
        <ul>
          <CustomLink to ="/">Home</CustomLink>
          <CustomLink to ="/projects">Projects</CustomLink>
          <CustomLink to ="/about">About</CustomLink>
          <CustomLink to ="/contact">Contact</CustomLink>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      );
}

function CustomLink({ to, children, ...props }) {
    const resolvedPath = useResolvedPath(to);
    //needs path to fully match, reconsider if adding querying from URL in future
    const isActive = useMatch({path: resolvedPath.pathname, end: true});
    return (
        <li className={isActive ? "active" : ""}>
            <Link to={to} {...props}>
                {children}
            </Link>
        </li>
    )
}
```

CSS:

```
.active{
    background-color: #30BCED;
}
```

I also tried nav li.active so far everything but the .active works in the CSS and by looking at the webpage inspector I can see that the currently active link is being given the active class name

Comment: Does moving the classname from the li to the Link help?

Comment: Found the problem, instead of using .modules.css just use .css for the styles class and import into the javascript(s) as css and not module

Answer (score 0):

You wrote down the `import styles from "./styles.module.css"`, but never used the `styles`.

You need to modify the code with below shows:

```
        <li className={isActive ? styles.active : ""}>
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            <Link to={to} {...props}>
                {children}
            </Link>
        </li>
```